# Docker bind ports in network host

Tags: docker, networking

I would like to keep the host's IP address and hostname for all my Docker containers, however, I would like to bind different ports as many of my containers have port 80 in use.
Now, I know that port binding doesn't work in network mode host, however, I am wondering if there are alternatives that can achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NGINX as a reverse proxy to expose only the port 80 and manage the container requests internally. It acts like a unique door to your containers:

https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx